# nodejs express-session middleware is not working in visual studio

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-2017, express-session

I'm trying to use express-session in nodejs express but I can't set or get sessions. I get "Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request'" when I'm trying to build.

I tried to change the order of the codes but nothing works

node version : v10.15.3

visual studio : 2017

my dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "session-file-store": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/debug": "0.0.30",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.37",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.0.50",
    "@types/mime": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/serve-static": "^1.7.32",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.87"
  }
```

app.ts

```
  var app = express();
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var session = require('express-session');
  var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
  app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
  app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support URL-encoded   bodies
  app.use(session({
      name: 'test-session-cookie-id',
      secret: 'test',
      resave: true,
      store: new FileStore(),
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { secure: true }
  }));
  // view engine setup
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'pug');

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


  app.use('/', routes);
  app.use('/users', users);
  app.use('/signup', signup);
  app.use('/verify', verify);

  app.use(function printSession(req, res, next) {
    console.log('req.session', req.session); //error
    return next();
  });
```

update :

module seems to be working fine itself . it created a session folder with 500+ files which is odd

update2 :

the express session is working fine but the error is bugging me. I uninstalled vs2017 and installed vs2019 and updated the typescript but the problem is still there

Comment: What build tool are you using? Looks like your linter/compiler doesn't know about the library you are using to extend express.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger i'm using visual studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was no `@types/express-session` in my `dependencies/devDependencies` . `npm install --save @types/express-session` did the job . there is no error now